# Как убрать с ответа created_at и updated_at?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

```
Route::get('/user', function () {
    return UserResource::collection(User::all());
});
```

Во время такого подхода с базы приходит 5к объектов соответственно с ненужными своими `created_at` и `updated_at`.Как можно убрать эти два параметра?

Хочу сделать через `protected`  но думаю такой вариант проста прячет эти два свойства.

```
protected $hidden = ["created_at", "updated_at"];
```

Мне надо убрать их из запроса чтобы повысить  производительность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1** (легкий, но не полный)

В [App\Http\Resource\User::to_array()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#concept-overview) уберите их из списка возвращаемых полей. Это не разгрузит запросы к базе для их извлечения, но разгрузит трафик между сервером и браузером, а также облегчит работу браузера.

**Вариант 2** (полный, но несколько утяжеленный)

Используйте Resource Controller. В нем в методе `index()` вместо обращения к коллекции ресурсов выполните прямые запросы к БД для получения нужных Вам данных в нужном формате. Обработайте их вручную и отдайте JSON как положено. Это позволит добиться максимального быстродействия при совместимости по форматам данных, но пойдет вразрез со стандартными приемами и будет являться "доработкой напильником".

Мне более импонирует Вариант 1. Второй стоит использовать только при *очень* жестких требованиях к быстродействию. IMHO.